# Best way to deploy Python Flask app with OpenCV on Azure

Tags: python, azure, opencv, pycharm, azure-web-app-service

I currently have a Flask application I created in Pycharm, which makes use of the opencv-python module. What is the best way to deploy this application on Microsoft Azure? Is there a specific Azure service which supports opencv? Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you tried my solution, is it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways to deploy flask app to azure. Like ftp, local git or other ways. The tools used for deployment are just methods to achieve the purpose of deployment, which method is almost the same.

[This blog](https://medium.com/@nikovrdoljak/deploy-your-flask-app-on-azure-in-3-easy-steps-b2fe388a589e) gives to a easy way to deploy flask app.

If you are curious about other deploymeny ways. Have a look of the [Offcial doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Fcontainers%2Ftoc.json).

Hope it helps.